# error using mutate_all toupper since string is of the form "13corte4"

Tags: r, string, dplyr, toupper

I am performing a mutate_all such as:

```
nome.serie <- "13corte4"
nome.serie <- mutate_all(nome.serie, funs=toupper)
```

but I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I have tried mutate_each and mutate_at as well. I have also tried this function:

```
upper_it = function(X){X %>% mutate_each_( funs(as.character(.)), names( . 
[sapply(., is.factor)] )) %>%
mutate_each_( funs(toupper), names( .[sapply(., is.character)] ))}
```

However the same error happens again and again

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nome.serie <- "13corte4"
DF <- data.frame(nome.serie = nome.serie)
DF <- mutate_all(DF, .funs=toupper)
DF
#  nome.serie
#1   13CORTE4
```

The error message states that the first argument in `mutate_all` should not be a character vector.